# Magento 2: How to display configurable product options in list page

Tags: magento2, category, configurable-product

How to Displaying configurable product options in the category list page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have show it by add code to file list.phtml:

```
<?php 
$_objectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productTypeInstance = $_objectManager->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable');
$productAttributeOptions = $productTypeInstance->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
if (!empty($productAttributeOptions)) { //check if product has custom options. If it doesn't go to the next product
    foreach($productAttributeOptions as $productAttributeOption){
        ?>
            <p><span><?php echo $productAttributeOption['label']; ?></span></p>
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $productAttributeOption['attribute_id'] ?>]" data-selector="super_attribute[151]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute151" class="super-attribute-select" aria-required="true">
                <?php
                    foreach($productAttributeOption['values'] as $configure_option)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $configure_option['value_index']; ?>"><?php echo $configure_option['label'] ?></option>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
                
            </select>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

@David Duong
This solution work for me but i have another problem this configuration is not updtated if simple product finish , custom attribute remains does not take off need more dynamic solution..